# '... Debugger undefined or null reference' error when WinDBG TTD Scripting with Javascript

Tags: debugging, windbg, javascript

I tried Javascript scripting on WinDbg (TTD specifically); but even in simple example I get error
`Unable to get property 'Debugger' of undefined or null reference`.
Line was simply `var ctl = host.namespace.Debugger.Utility.Control;` but it does not work.
Does TTD have Debugger property? I cannot find any specific document about scripting for TTD; so I assume they have the same interface with regular session. How can we send commands to debugger from a script in TTD sessions?

Comment: has the jsprovider been loaded  .load jsprovider.dll ;  .chain
then try printing with debugLog() to check

Comment: I was trying to use it as a global variable; but it seems that's only usable inside a function.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this applies to your situation, but the namespace property of host doesn't appear to get set by the jsprovider until after initializeScript is called.  So if that line is in your initializeScript function or one that is called from initializeScript namespace doesn't exist yet.

Comment: I was trying to use it as a global variable; but it seems that's only usable inside a function.